# CSS Width not being set as expected

Tags: html, css, sass

I have the following. As you can see, I have a row with two columns. I set the first column to a width of 90%, and the second column to a width of 10%. But as you can see, the columns are the same length.

[image]

I have the following css:

```
.message-footer-col {
  width: 90%;
}

.message-footer-button-col {
  width: 10%;
}
```

If anyone can advise how I can adjust each columns width, I would appreciate it.  Thanks

**UPDATE**

I am using an Ionic2 framework that generates the raw html.  Here is my code:

```
<ion-footer class="message-footer">
  <form #f="ngForm">
    <ion-grid class="message-footer-grid">
      <ion-row class="message-footer-row">
        <ion-col class="message-footer-col">
          <ion-input class="message-footer-input" [(ngModel)]="message" name="messageText" required placeholder="message..."></ion-input>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col class="message-footer-button-col">
          <button class="message-footer-button" (click)="messageSend(f.value, f.valid)" full [disabled]="f.valid === false"><ion-icon class="message-send" name="send"></ion-icon></button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </form>
</ion-footer>
```

Comment: please show your actual html, not a picture of it.  I'm guessing it something to do with the size of one of the parent containers

Comment: See UPDATE above.  I am using Ionic, so the html code is generated.

Comment: just use the col classes from ionic; `<ion-col class="message-footer-col col-8">` ; I think the ion-col overwrites yours

Comment: Thanks @Mazz, but that seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First remove col class as it has some flex properties,
then apply `display:block;` to the columns.